# How to solve this javascript loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, date

I want it to be in loop. any idea? or is it not possible? should i do loop in php instead? the idea is to check if today or tomorrow date are listed inside the date that is not available to be selected.

```
//array
var disabledArr = ["09/29/2019","09/30/2019"];
//for loop
var j = disabledArr.length;
//convert date
function formatDate(date) {
    var d = new Date(date),enter code here
        month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
        day = '' + d.getDate(),
        year = d.getFullYear();

    if (month.length < 2) 
        month = '0' + month;
    if (day.length < 2) 
        day = '0' + day;

    return [month, day, year].join('/');
}

    var today = new Date();
    var today1 = formatDate(today);
    var n = disabledArr.includes(today1);
    if(n == true){
        today.setDate(today.getDate() + 1);
    }
    var today2 = formatDate(today);
    var n = disabledArr.includes(today2);
    if(n == true){
        today.setDate(today.getDate() + 1);
    }
    var today3 = formatDate(today);
    var n = disabledArr.includes(today3);
    if(n == true){
        today.setDate(today.getDate() + 1);
    }
    var today4 = formatDate(today);
```

Comment: *any idea?* `for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++`

Comment: how do I declare variable today every loop so it will be today1, today2, today3...if on php I can use $today.$i

Comment: Why `var d = new Date(date)`? You don't do anything to modify *date*, so why copy it?

Comment: i found the solution. basically i need to create an array and push output of formatDate in a loop

`var today = new Date();
var todayy = [];
todayy.push(formatDate(today));
for(i=0;i<disabledArr.length;i++){   
if(todayy[i] == disabledArr[i]){   
today.setDate(today.getDate() + 1);
}
todayy.push(formatDate(today));  
}`